# How to grab last modified file with certain keyword on page

Tags: php, regex

I have a snippet of code here that grabs the last modified file from a directory. However, I want it to exclude any file that has the word "placeholder" written on it. How do I modify this so that it does exclude those files, especially since the file that has "placeholder" written on its page is usually the last modified file?

Here is the code that I have:

```
<?php
$dir = "path goes here";         
$pattern = '\.(php)$'; // check only file with these ext.          
$newstamp = 0;            
$newname = "";

if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {               
       while (false !== ($fname = readdir($handle)))  {            
         // Eliminate current directory, parent directory            
         if (ereg('^\.{1,2}$',$fname)) continue;            
         // Eliminate other pages not in pattern            
         if (! ereg($pattern,$fname)) continue;            
         $timedat = filemtime("$dir/$fname");            
         if ($timedat > $newstamp) {
            $newstamp = $timedat;
            $newname = $fname;
          }
         }
        }
closedir ($handle);
$name = basename($newname,".php");
 echo "<b><span class='latestch'>Latest Chapter:</span></b>  <a href=url-path-goes-here".$newname."> $name</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip over files which contain the string "placeholder":

```
if(strpos(file_get_contents($fname), 'placeholder') !== false) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks much! This has helped. I just had to change $fname to $dir/$fname

Answer (score 0):

You could save a lot of code:

```
array_multisort(
    array_map('filemtime', 
        $files = preg_grep('/placeholder/',
            glob("$dir/*.php"), PREG_GREP_INVERT)),
    SORT_ASC, $files);

$name = basename(end($files), '.php');
```